# What is the interaction between color channels in a convolutional net?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am wondering how the color channels interact in a convolutional net:

1. Is it correct that a 2D kernel is applied to every single (color) channel resulting in independent outputs, the information is only combined in a fully connected layer?
2. If I want my net to take advantage of the information contained in the different channels, can I use a 3D convolution with a 3D kernel? (I am solving a task which doesn't include image recognition rather includes multiple 2D matrices including different information each - I want to find certain correlations between these 2D matrices)
3. Based on the above: Tensorflow includes functions for 2D-Convolution which takes a [in_height,in_width,in_channels]-input and for 3D-Convolution which takes a [in_height,in_width,in_depth,in_channels]-input. If I set [2,2,2] (example; for 2D) and [2,2,2,1] (for 3D), do they perform the same operation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out...

Using 2d conv will use a 3d kernel as well (across channels), however strides are zero into the channel direction. Thus resulting in a 2D matrix as output.

Using 3d conv will use a 3d kernel (across h,w,d) & have strides in all directions. Resulting in a 3D matrix as output.

Cheers